# What's best for vb.net Winforms background worker process spanning all forms?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I have a WinForms application that is not MDI and will use various forms for different work that users will do in a wireless mode.  I want to create a WiFi signal checker and give the user a visual indicator on a status strip of that their current network signal is like (black, red, yellow, green).

To do this I think I want to create a `BackgroundWorker` from `MyApplication_Startup()` and have that worker periodically sample the signal quality.  I would need to kill the worker on application shutdown.  I would have a public variable in the My namespace for signal quality that all forms could check, and the background worker would keep updated every n seconds.

I've never done anything like this before and none of my searches have turned up a likely looking solution.  Has anyone done this who might have sample code they would be willing to share?  I'm not sure if my approach is the right one yet.

Comment: Hi Rascal and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a few minutes to read over the [FAQ]. Now, down to business. You have a question here in the form of **"How do I do this?"**; generally not a valuable question. The community typically likes to see and answer **"I tried this, but got this error, how do I fix this?"**. You may be lucky and find a brave soul to do your work for you (including all the research, planning, etc.), but chances are, this question will sit and rot. Please consider trying something out first and letting us know how it doesn't work. Maybe it just might work anyway!

Comment: This is unlikely to be the proper solution, given that obtaining the wifi state doesn't cost a lot of cpu cycles.  Use a Timer instead.

Comment: Thanks, Hans! It's been since VB6 that I wrote a winforms app and I seemed to recall that the timer pulled focus out of other events.  If that's no longer the case I agree.  I had thought of that first but shied away.  To Dan, I agree, I wasn't so much looking for someone to do my work as to validate whether I was on the right track before investing a lot of time.  Cheers!